# getting error as 'payroll' object has no attribute '_payroll__empid'

Tags: python

class payroll(workers,department):
def compute(self):
workers.gets(self)
department.gets(self)
if self._basicsalary<30000:
self.__hra=self._basicsalary*2/100
self.__ca=self._basicsalary*2.5/100
self.__med=self._basicsalary*3/100
self.__pf=self._basicsalary*7.5/100
elif self._basicsalary>=30000 and self._basicsalary<70000:
self.__hra=self._basicsalary*2.5/100
self.__ca=self._basicsalary*3/100
self.__med=self._basicsalary*3.5/100
self.__pf=self._basicsalary*7.5/100
else:
self.__hra=self._basicsalary*3/100
self.__ca=self._basicsalary*3.5/100
self.__med=self._basicsalary*4/100
self.__pf=self._basicsalary*7.5/100
self.__gp=self.__hra+self.__ca+self.__med-self.__pf
print("gp:",self.__gp)

```
def insertion(self):
    c1=c.connection1()
    conn=c1.getconnection()
    cur=conn.cursor()
    query="insert into employee values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    val=(self.__empid,self.__empname,self.__dob,self.__addr,self.__mobile,self.__email,self.__city,self.__deptid,self.__deptname,self._basicsalary,
         self.__hra,self.__ca,self.__med,self.__pf,self.__gp)
    try:
        cur.execute(query,val)
    except Exception as el:
        print("Error in query")
        print(el)
    else:
        conn.commit()
        print("Record Saved Successfully")
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting); make sure you show your code exactly as you actually have it; make sure you use full English sentences *in the question itself* in order to *explain the problem* with context (What is the purpose of the code? How do you try to use the code? What happens when you do that, what is supposed to happen instead, and how is that different?); and most importantly, make sure you **ask a question** starting with a question word like "how" or "why" and ending with a question mark (`?`).

Comment: But as a hint: where the code says `self.__empid`, *why should that mean anything at all*? Where is that value supposed to come from? Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to diagnose the problem yourself first.